# Remove multiple spaces to a single space in sybase

Tags: t-sql, sybase

i am using below query to remove consecutive multiple spaces to a single space . the loop is not coming out where did i made mistake . please help me out with this or if anyother better idea to handle this.

```
DECLARE @MEME_LAST_NAME  VARCHAR(22)
select @MEME_LAST_NAME = 'Kawamur    a        '

      WHILE (PATINDEX('%   %', @MEME_LAST_NAME ) > 0)
      BEGIN

      SET @MEME_LAST_NAME = STR_REPLACE(@MEME_LAST_NAME,'   ','')

      END
select @MEME_LAST_NAME

output should be : 'Kawamur a '
```

Answer (score 1):

replace space with null
select str_replace('Kawamur             a         ',"  " ,NULL)

Comment: This should have been upvoted long ago.  It's the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
set nocount on
declare @mesg_text varchar(50)
  select @mesg_text = "'Kawamur    a        '"
  while (charindex("  ",@mesg_text) > 0)
      begin
      select @mesg_text = str_replace(@mesg_text,"  "," ")
      end
 select @mesg_text
```

---

'Kawamur a '

Single quotes put on string only to highlight single space at the end.